# How to overwrite value returned by Capabilities.os in as3?

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I have a swf file which will load another swf file developed by a third party. I don't want it to know my `os`, so I want to modify the return value by `Capabilities.os`. My operating system is `windows server 2016`. I searched for ways like overwriting the method or changing windows registry, but ended up with nothing. So I wonder is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot, I think. This functionality is provided by Flash Player runtime to allow the app to learn the **reliable** information about environment. However, if you have that third-party SWF in your possession (rather then load it from elsewhere) you can modify its code so it will get a predefined string rather than read **Capabilities.os**. Also, why that is a problem for you?

Comment: Then can I change the computer information like modifying the windows registry? The code can't be modified by me, it's not holden by me. Thanks.

Comment: _"I don't want it to know my OS"_ Why not is the question. What's so bad? What's purpose of third-party swf? Maybe there's an alternative. PS: Changing Windows registry is a bad idea (the next restart could lead to a not working computer).